# Mysql Select recent 2 records for each group[user]

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, group-concat

I have two tables **users** and **login_track**. Each user may or may not have login records in login_track table. I want to retrieve recent 2 login dates for each user.

Table structure is as below:
Users:

```
  user_id  name
     1     John
     2     Mike
     3     Anderson
     4     William
    .....
```

Login_track table:

```
  track_id   user_id   login_date
   100           1    2017-06-20
   101           1    2017-06-21
   102           2    2017-06-21
   103           1    2017-06-23
   104           2    2017-06-23
   105           1    2017-06-27
```

**So desired result should be**:

```
  user_id  Name          login_date
    1      John          2017-06-27, 2017-06-23
    2      Mike          2017-06-23, 2017-06-21
    3      Anderson      NULL
    4      William       NULL
```

Note : User id 3 (Anderson) and 4 (William) has no records in login_track table, even though those two should also list in the final result with NULL value to login_date column.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky as MySQL don't have ROW_NUMBER() function. Hence with a simple trick, try this :

```
Select u.user_id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT iq.login_date) login_date
FROM(
select user_id,  login_date
from 
(
   select user_id, login_date,
      (@num:=if(@group = user_id, @num +1, if(@group := user_id, 1, 1))) row_number 
  from Login_track 
  CROSS JOIN (select @num:=0, @group:=null) c
  order by user_id, login_date DESC
) as x 
where x.row_number <= 2
    )iq
right join users u on u.user_id = iq.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

output :

```
user_id name        login_date
------- ----        -----------
1   John        2017-06-23,2017-06-27
2   Mike        2017-06-21,2017-06-23
3   Anderson    NULL
4   William     NULL
```

Comment: I need all the records from user table, from your solution users without records in login_track is not listing.

Comment: Share more sample data so I can verify ?

Answer (score 1):

You can user `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT substring_index(group_concat(login_date SEPARATOR ','), ',', 2) AS login_date FROM `Users` LEFT JOIN `Login_track` ON `Login_track`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Comment: He want only 2 login_date not all

Comment: @jenish, users may have zero or many records in login track table.

Comment: you can set required condition in where condition for further improve this query @orangetime

Comment: so you don't need those data whose `login_data` is null... Am i right?

Comment: Required login_date as NULL, if login track not exists for any user.

Comment: then you have to get data from `uses table` and `left join users` with `Login_track` table..

Comment: @Jenish, tried but instead of newest records, it is pulling old login date